# PHP read TXT file from a special character

Tags: php

I have a TXT file (example.txt) which includes the following:

```
text1
text2
text3
@
new text1
new text2
new text3
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

$open = fopen('example.txt','r');
while (!feof($open)) {
    $getTextLine = trim(fgets($open));

    if ( $getTextLine == '@' ) {
        echo fgets($open). "<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

How to read all lines of TXT file after the @ character and save an array? I would like to the output is

```
new text1
new text2
new text3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice short answer is to just read the whole file in and extract the piece of text from `PHP_EOL.'@'.PHP_EOL` to make sure that it finds an `@` on a line on it's own.  Then trim off the `PHP_EOL` and the `@` off the start.  Finally to split to an array, use explode of the remainder...

```
$text = file_get_contents("a.txt");
$end = ltrim(strstr($text, PHP_EOL."@".PHP_EOL ), PHP_EOL."@");
$out = explode(PHP_EOL,  $end);
print_r($out);
```

If you had a file with...

```
text1
text2
text3
@
new text1
new text2
new text3
--
aaa
```

You can use `strstr()` again to pick out the content from the `@` and then before the `--` line...

```
$text = file_get_contents("a.txt");
$end = ltrim(strstr($text, PHP_EOL."@".PHP_EOL ), PHP_EOL."@");
$end = strstr($end, PHP_EOL."--".PHP_EOL, true);
$out = explode(PHP_EOL,  $end);
print_r($out);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => new text1
    [1] => new text2
    [2] => new text3
)
```

Comment: If the last line in TXT file contains "--" character for example, how to read lines between "@" and "--"?

Comment: I've updated the code, check that the text file is what your expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code using PHP :

```
<?php
$input=file_get_contents("example.txt");
$lines=explode("\n",$input);
$status=false;
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if($status === false && $line === "@")
    {
        $status=true;
    }
    else if($status === true)
    {
        echo("-->");
        echo($line);
        echo("\n");
    }
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$lines = file("example.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES  |  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$status=false;
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    if($status === false && $line === "@")
    {
        $status=true;
    }
    else if($status === true)
    {
        echo("-->");
        echo($line);
        echo("\n");
    }
}
?>
```

---

example.txt file :

```
text1
text2
text3
@
new text1
new text2
new text3
```

---

Output :

```
-->new text1
-->new text2
-->new text3
-->
-->
```

---

New Update :

```
<?php
$file = file("example.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES  |  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$status=false;
$list=array();
foreach ($file as $line)
{
    if($status === false && $line === "@")
    {
        $status=true;
    }
    else if($status === true)
    {
        echo("-->");
        echo($line);
        echo("\n");
        $list[]=$line;
    }
}
print_r($list);
?>
```

Output of Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => new text1
    [1] => new text2
    [2] => new text3
)
```

Comment: explode? Use `file()` which takes care of cross platform line endings and is designed for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with this:

```
<?php
// Read file.
$filename = 'example.txt';
$file = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Read lines
$output = array();
$found = false;
foreach ($file as $row) {
    if ($row == '@') {
        $found = true;
        continue;
    }
    if ($found) {
        $output[] = $row;   
    }   
}

// Output
print_r($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about read the file into memory using `file()` (warning: it might be inefcient if this is a very large file) and then delete the lines untill you reach a line containing `@`

```
$lines = file('example.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
    if (stripos($line, '@') === false) {
        unset($lines[$i]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```